# Android MediaRecorder. Continue recording after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediarecorder, onconfigurationchanged

I have simple app that records audio using `MediaRecorder` class. When screen orientation changes audio recording stops.
How can I continue recording after screen rotation? Is `android:configChanges="orientation"` the only way?

Comment: maybe the problem is not in the media recording, how are you handling the screen rotation and the recreation of activity or fragment?

Comment: I use onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance() to save data from old activity. And getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance() to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and move the `MediaRecorder` reference and recording logic to a `Fragment` with no UI that will be retained across the orientation change. To achieve this, you should mark the fragment instance using `setRetainInstance(true)`.

Comment: Thanks I followed your advice. Now my app works as i want it to.